# ming 0.4.2 compilation errors on Ubuntu 12.04 when installing from source code

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-12.04, libpng, ming

I am trying to install ming 0.4.2 from source code and **it was compilable before on Ubuntu 10.04**, but now it' giving following compilation errors when I try to install using command `sudo make install` (`libpng` is already installed).

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -DSWF_LITTLE_ENDIAN   -o img2swf img2swf.o ../src/libming.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -DSWF_LITTLE_ENDIAN -o .libs/img2swf img2swf.o  ../src/.libs/libming.so
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src -I../src    -g -O2 -Wall -DSWF_LITTLE_ENDIAN -MT png2dbl.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/png2dbl.Tpo -c -o png2dbl.o png2dbl.c
png2dbl.c: In function ‘readPNG’:
png2dbl.c:64:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
mv -f .deps/png2dbl.Tpo .deps/png2dbl.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -DSWF_LITTLE_ENDIAN   -o png2dbl png2dbl.o ../src/libming.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -DSWF_LITTLE_ENDIAN -o .libs/png2dbl png2dbl.o  ../src/.libs/libming.so
png2dbl.o: In function `readPNG':
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:69: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:74: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:82: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:97: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:98: undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:99: undefined reference to `png_read_info'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:101: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:127: undefined reference to `png_get_valid'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:156: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:158: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:162: undefined reference to `png_get_channels'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:187: undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:194: undefined reference to `png_read_image'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:128: undefined reference to `png_set_expand'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:135: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:143: undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:151: undefined reference to `png_set_filler'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:125: undefined reference to `png_set_packing'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:107: undefined reference to `png_get_valid'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:117: undefined reference to `png_get_PLTE'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:78: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:92: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:86: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
png2dbl.o: In function `writeDBL':
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:278: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:280: undefined reference to `compress2'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:278: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util/png2dbl.c:280: undefined reference to `compress2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [png2dbl] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gmuhammad/Downloads/ming-0.4.2/util'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you linking to libpng? You could try to add -lpng. Edit: Didn't catch the time-stamp there..

Comment: it is libpng version problem (12.04 LTS has some upgraded version of libpng), So I upgraded the ming to 0.4.4, and now it's compiling but I didn't check the run time, and now I am out of my town but when I'll return I'll check it out whether it's working properly or not.